# Is it possible to have two serialEvent() in Arduino code?

Tags: c++, softwareserial

I am developing a code on Arduino and need to implement a condition that if data is available form "serial2" then only get the input for "Serial" terminal of Arduino.

I have tried with below code, but its behavior is when I am sending something from "serial" terminal of arduino, control goes into the loop "serialEvent()" otherwise even if I am sending the data over "serial2" it is not entering in that loop.

Below is my code snippet:

```
void serialEvent() 
{
  int DATAaddressMSb, DATAaddressLSb;
  digitalWrite(DIR485, LOW);
  delay(100);
  delay(10);
  while (Serial2.available()>0)
  {
    Serial.println("serial2 data available");
    int i = 0;
    int bufferIn1[9] = { int(0x00), int(0x00), int(0x00), int(0x00), int(0x00), int(0x00), int(0x00), int(0x00), int(0x00) };
    bufferIn1[i] = Serial2.read();
    Serial.print(bufferIn1[i], DEC);
    Serial.print(" ");
    if(i == 0){Serial.print("BUFFER VAL 0");
    Serial.print( bufferIn1[i], DEC);}
    if(i == 1){Serial.print("BUFFER VAL 1");
    Serial.print( bufferIn1[i], DEC);}
    if(i == 2){Serial.print("BUFFER VAL 2");
    Serial.print( bufferIn1[i], DEC);}
    i++;
  }

  while (Serial.available()&& pos < sizeof my_str - 1) {
    char c = Serial.read();
    if (c == '\n') {            // \n means "end of message"
            my_str[pos] = '\0';     // terminate the buffer
            pos = 0;                // reset to start of buffer
            String str((char*)my_str);    // converte char array in string
            if (str == "PCB-CODE") { Serial.println(SN_CODE); }
            if (str == "FW-VERSION") { Serial.println(FW_ver); }
            if (str == "STOP" ) { TESTcode = 0; IDcode = 999; }
            if (str == "TEST1") { TESTcode = 1; delay(6000); Serial.println("Enter ID "); }
            if (str == "TEST2") { Serial.println("Initialising Board ");  delay(6000); TESTcode = 2; }           // For all tests

            if (str == "ID0") { IDcode = 999; }
            if (str == "ID1") { delay(60); IDcode = 1; }       // Test for FW version
            if (str == "ID2") { IDcode = 2; }       // Test for 3.3V
            if (str == "ID3") { IDcode = 3; }       // Test for Main power
            if (str == "ID4") { delay(50); IDcode = 4; }       // Test for +15V
            if (str == "ID5") { IDcode = 5; }       // Test for +10V
            if (str == "ID6") { IDcode = 6; }       // Test for +8V
            if (str == "ID7") { IDcode = 7; }       // Test for +5.5V
            if (str == "ID8") { IDcode = 8; }       // Test for +1.2V
            if (str == "ID9") { IDcode = 9; }       // Test for +2.5V
            if (str == "ID10") { IDcode = 10; }     // Test for -15V
            if (str == "ID11") { IDcode = 11; }     // Test for POW_LIGHT
            if (str == "ID12") { IDcode = 12; }     // Test for +s_stab
            if (str == "ID13") {delay(50); IDcode = 13; }     // Test for +CELLA
            if (str == "ID14") { IDcode = 14; }     // Test for FPGA_GPIO
            if (str == "ID15") { IDcode = 15; }     // Test for DAC_OUT
            if (str == "ID16") { IDcode = 16; }     // Test for CURRENT_LOOP
            if (str == "ID17") {delay(50); IDcode = 17; }     // Test for Torque signal
            if (str == "ID18") { IDcode = 18; }     // Test for EXT_TRIGGER
            if (str == "ID19") { IDcode = 19; }     // Test for Encoder
            if (str == "ID20") { IDcode = 20; }     // Test for RAM
            if (str == "ID21") { IDcode = 21; }     // Test for SD Card
            if (str == "ID22") { IDcode = 22; }     // Test for Ethernet
            if (str == "ID23") { IDcode = 23; }     // Test for CAN
            if (str == "ID24") { IDcode = 24; }     // Test for I2C
     for( int i = 0; i < sizeof(my_str);  ++i )    // resetta la stringa ricevuta         // reset the received string
          my_str[i] = (char)0;
        }
        else {my_str[pos++] = c;}
  }          
 }
```

Please guide. Thank you........

Comment: ignore the SerialEvent and put this code in loop(). it is nothing more then `if (Serial.available())` called after the loop() function

Comment: Relevant Arduino source code: https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-avr/blob/b7c607663fecc232e598f2c0acf419ceb0b7078c/cores/arduino/HardwareSerial.cpp#L64-L85

Answer (score 1):

According to https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/SerialEvent

Arduino Mega handles:

```
void serialEvent1(){
//statements
}

void serialEvent2(){
//statements
}

void serialEvent3(){
//statements
}
```

Every other Arduino has only single:

```
void serialEvent(){
//statements
}
```